# Reducer getting null for key and value

Tags: hadoop

I have my map defined as

```
public static class FlightMapper 
    extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {...}
```

I have my reducer class defined as

```
public static class FlightReducer
    extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {...}
```

My reducer constructor:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Text values, 
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {...}
```

But in my reducer in reducer constructor, when I am printing key and value is comes null. 
My main function:

```
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    job.setNumReduceTasks(4);
    job.setJarByClass(FlightData.class);
    job.setMapperClass(FlightMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setReducerClass(FlightReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

I am new to Hadoop so this might be some small mistake. Please help.

Comment: Why is the class for KEYIN in your Mapper an `Object`?  Shouldn't it be `Text`, like all others?

Comment: In mapper it is Object because I wanted offset of the line form the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, did not use Iteratable in the constructor, hence the reducer was not finding the required constructor.